# Issue while accessing database in mongodb using prisma orm and college network

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

i have created my database in mongodb and using prisma as server connection when i push my data using any other network weather my wifi from phone or some other wifi it gets pushed but when i try to do the same with my college wifi network it fails why

Solution to bypass or rectify this problem

Comment: Hello - pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask